# MFSideMenu full size pan gesture

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I use MFSideMenu in my application, and i can show the menu using a pan gesture on the navigation bar only. I would like it to work on the whole screen, like on the facebook app.!

[image]

I've tried changing this line (l.39 in MFSideMenuManager.m)

```
[controller.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

to this :

```
[controller.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

but it just won't work.

Do you have any idea of what i should edit for it to work?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally succeeded making it work. The gesture is actually already implemented but working only if the menu is hidden. We have to remove 2 conditions to make sure it works both ways

There are two lines to edit in the MFSideMenuManager.m

In the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: method

```
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        if([gestureRecognizer.view isEqual:self.navigationController.view] && 
           self.navigationController.menuState != MFSideMenuStateHidden) return YES;
```

becomes

```
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        if([gestureRecognizer.view isEqual:self.navigationController.view]) return YES;
```

In the navigationControllerPanned: method, just remove the if line

```
- (void) navigationControllerPanned:(id)sender {
    if(self.navigationController.menuState == MFSideMenuStateHidden) return;

    [self handleNavigationBarPan:sender];
}
```

becomes

```
- (void) navigationControllerPanned:(id)sender {
    [self handleNavigationBarPan:sender];
}
```

And it works!

It is not a really good practice to edit a library, but it is easy if you want to go further to add a boolean option to MFSideMenu to make it configurable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the MFSideMenuManager but if the bar is draggable I expect it to have a UIPanGestureRecognizer with a line

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

So what you do is replace the navigation bar with the view for the whole navigation controller

```
[self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: That's what i tried before, but unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks anyways